# Extract values from JSON AIP response

Tags: c#, json, json.net

A response from a restful API returns some JSON:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "href": "http://localhost:54398/"
  },
  "busPartner": {
    "href": "http://localhost:54398/BusPartner",
    "rel": [
      "collection"
    ]
  },
  "busPartnerType": {
    "href": "http://localhost:54398/BusPartnerType",
    "rel": [
      "collection"
    ]
  },
  "busPartnerPossAttrib": {
    "href": "http://localhost:54398/BusPartnerPossAttribs",
    "rel": [
      "collection"
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to extract a list of `href` values from the JSON.  While I can use `JsonTextReader` as below and take the values I need out of the resulting list...

```
IList<string>  tt = new List<string>();
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(response));
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value != null)
    {
        tt.Add( reader.TokenType + " " + reader.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        tt.Add(reader.TokenType.ToString());
    }
}
```

...it is clumsy and tedious.  There must be a better way.  Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JObjects) to extract the list:

```
List<string> tt = JObject.Parse(response)
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(jp => jp.Name == "href" && jp.Value.Type == JTokenType.String)
    .Select(jp => (string)jp.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sAf26B

Comment: thanks this has put me well on track with my part of the project, worked straight copy and past :)